# Cache files being set by magento to 0600

Tags: cache, magento-1, permissions, magento-1.5

I'm running **magento 1.5** and in logs I see a lot of errors:

> var/cache/mage--5/mage---internal-metadatas---080_CONFIG_GLOBAL_CRONTAB):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

the permissions for files in `cache/mage--0/mage-- are 0600`. Which I think is wrong and should be `0644`. But when I reset them after an hour they get back to  0600. I think the magento cron user is wrong or something in that direction but cannot progress any further.

Any ideas where to look?

I think the issue started when I applied the 7405 v.1.1 supee patch, but not 100% sure.

Tried resetting permissions, deleting cache, varnish etc.

Comment: What are the permissions on the `var` folder ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism 777

Comment: Recursively ? It should be 777 recursively `chmod -R 777 var/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the issue was that the indexer cron was set to execute as root instead of magento user.